# sum of invertible matrix and a diagonal matrix with positive entries is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets assume I'm given an invertible matrix $A$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ with positive entries on the diagonal. Is the matrix

$$ B:= A+D$$

then always invertible? How to prove this or is there a reference for this?

Comment: Nope, counterexample: $A = -I$ and $D = I$.